# NavigationPage + CarouselPage: weird scroll error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

I am playing with the `CarouselPage` example right now, and since I'd like to move to other pages, I am starting the application with a `NavigationPage` as the main one:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Need navigation to have modal/nonmodal pages
        //MainPage = new MainPage();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
```

The XAML adds safe areas for the iPhone X, and removes the navigation bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stoa" x:Class="Test.MainPage"
              xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
              ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true" 
              NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">            
    <ContentPage>
        <ContentPage.Padding>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="0,40,0,0" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </ContentPage.Padding>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Green" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Button BackgroundColor="Green" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage>
        <ContentPage.Padding>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="0,40,0,0" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </ContentPage.Padding>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Blue" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Button BackgroundColor="Blue" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</CarouselPage>
```

The problem is that now the user **can scroll vertically** and it loses the margins, apparently:

[image: weirdscroll]

Is there a way to fix this?

In alternative, how can I navigate away from a carousel view or "fake" a carousel?

Answer (score 4):

> This "Safe Area scroll offset" can be fixed with a custom iOS CarouselPageRenderer that sets the UIScrollView
>   ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior to **Never**
>
> **Updated:** previous code example checked UIView.Subviews[0] is UIScrollView in OnElementChanged, this could throw a System.IndexOutOfRangeException causing a SIGABRT crash. So instead we check it in ViewDidLoad as suggested here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104385/ios-11-carousel-page-issues

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CarouselPage), typeof(CustomCarouselPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomCarouselPageRenderer : CarouselPageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            //Prevent vertical carousel scroll on iOS 11, 
            //we only want horizontal scroll in the carousel
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
            {
             View.Subviews.OfType<UIScrollView>().Single().ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior =
             UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.Never;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works better if you use Large titles in the navBar

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CarouselPage), typeof(CustomCarouselPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomCarouselPageRenderer : CarouselPageRenderer
    {
        // Override the OnElementChanged method so we can tweak this renderer post-initial setup
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            UIView view = NativeView;
            var scrollView = (UIScrollView)view.Subviews[0];
            scrollView.ContentSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(scrollView.ContentSize.Width, scrollView.Frame.Size.Height);
            AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
        }
    }
}
```